# Sacn Topic interpretation

Tags: ros, data, scan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Can I know how to interpret lidar data obtained on scan topic. I am using Hokuyo UST-10LX. Are the published values in cms or m ? I could not get this from the datasheet.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238011/sacn-topic-interpretation/) by [asdfgf](https://answers.ros.org/users/26977/asdfgf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 42 on 2016-06-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The  [sensor_msgs/LaserScan](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html) message has the range in metres. What the sensor puts out doesn't matter, it is the ROS API that counts.

---

Originally posted by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) with karma: 955 on 2016-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0